# VS2015: How to download VS2015 Pro after VS2017 was released?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I purchased a VS2015 Pro license through my company. No I need to install it on a fresh machine, but I made the mistake of not keeping an offline copy. I have not left a stone unturned on [visualstudio.com](http://www.visualstudio.com), but short of paying up for MSDN, I don't how to get a copy of VS2015 Pro ***(which I have purchased)***.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a MSDN subscription you can join the "Dev essentials" program for free.

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: Thanks, that did it.
For everyone else, follow the link above and got to the download page and use the search bar to look for what you want to download.